# How can I use InPersonSigner from one Docusign Account, or multiple Agents in the field?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have a need for In Person Signatures in the field, at many locations, and many different persons handling the signature process, at the same time.

Example:

- Field Agent collects user data, and does an in person signing for
  the document created with that data.
- Handle with 200 field persons simultaneously

I have some code that handles logging in to the DocuSign account using the UserName=DocusignAccountEmailAddress, and SignerName=PersonWhoActuallySignsDocument.

What I need to know is:

Can I include multiple persons to have access to this account?  If so, how?  I'm in the Dev SandBox currently.
If I can set them up, how do I specify which user to email the InPersonSinging Session to for the single account?

How do I use a single account (for one billing) to accomplish this, and know which Field Agent handled the In Person signing session?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add users to your account (log in to sandbox and go to preferences, then users).  Each user in turn will need to have their own DocuSign account.  You can further assign users to groups with permissions (including custom groups you define).

Troy